# Ho to do a simple function in R?

Tags: r, function, statistics, economics

I have the following df:

```
        library(tidyverse)
        df <- 
        tibble::tribble(
        ~ city_code, ~ name, ~ score,
        489, "Jonh"  , .45,
        489, "Adam"  , .51,
        128, "Mary"  , .33,
        128, "Matt"  , .29,
        147, "Rob"   , .45,
        147, "Gomez" , .55,
        199, "Thomas", .22,
        199, "Ryan"  , .60
        )
```

The original df has thousands of rows with two names for each city. For each city, I want to subtract the first person's score from the second and vice versa. The df should look like this:

```
df <- 
  tibble::tribble(
    ~ city_code, ~ name, ~ score, ~ score_diff,
    489, "Jonh"  , .45 , -.06 ,
    489, "Adam"  , .51 , .06 ,
    128, "Mary"  , .33 , .04 ,
    128, "Matt"  , .29 , -.04 ,
    147, "Rob"   , .45 , -.1 ,
    147, "Gomez" , .55 , .1 ,
    199, "Thomas", .22 , -.38 ,
    199, "Ryan"  , .60 , .38 ,
  )
```

Thanks in advance. I also appreciate any tips on how to learn these kinds of functions in R.

Answer (score 1):

Will work correctly, if there are exactly two names per city_code

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- 
  tibble::tribble(
    ~ city_code, ~ name, ~ score,
    489, "Jonh"  , .45,
    489, "Adam"  , .51,
    128, "Mary"  , .33,
    128, "Matt"  , .29,
    147, "Rob"   , .45,
    147, "Gomez" , .55,
    199, "Thomas", .22,
    199, "Ryan"  , .60
  )
df %>% group_by(city_code) %>%
  mutate(score_diff = score - lag(score, default = last(score)))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#> # Groups:   city_code [4]
#>   city_code name   score score_diff
#>       <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1       489 Jonh    0.45    -0.06  
#> 2       489 Adam    0.51     0.06  
#> 3       128 Mary    0.33     0.0400
#> 4       128 Matt    0.29    -0.0400
#> 5       147 Rob     0.45    -0.1   
#> 6       147 Gomez   0.55     0.1   
#> 7       199 Thomas  0.22    -0.38  
#> 8       199 Ryan    0.6      0.38
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>